# How can I get just the entries that match one condition?

Tags: c#, linq, aspnetboilerplate

I want to check if there in my table are entries that match my condition, I mean, I have this :

```
   [Required, MinLength(10), MaxLength(100)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [Required, MinLength(10), MaxLength(240)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Metric Metric { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float InitialValue { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float TargetValue { get; set; }

    public bool KeyTaskCheck { get; set; }
```

I want to get all the entries that KeyTaskCheck = true, how can i Do that with Asp.net Boilerplate

Comment: Please, post a little bit more code to help us to help you :). What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Asp.net Boilerplate. Luckily you do, and you know how to extract data from it:

```
IEnumerable<TableRow> myTableRows = ...
```

(or IQueryable, or List, etc)

TableRow is a class with the properties you wrote in your question. It represents one item of the fetched sequence of items. One of the properties of TableRow is the Boolean property KeyTaskCheck

> From my sequence of TableRow objects in myTableRows, give me only those that have a true value for property KeyTaskCheck.

Whenever you have an IEnumerable / IQueryable sequence of similar objects, and you want to keep only those object that match some predicate, you should use [Enumerable.Where](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8)

It is helpful to use plural nouns as identifiers for sequences, and singular nouns as identifier for one element in the sequence.

```
var result = myTableRows.Where(tableRow => tableRow.KeyTaskCheck);
```

In words: from the sequence of TableRow objects in myTableRows, keep only those TableRow objects that have a true value for property KeyTaskCheck.

The part `x => F(x)` in a LINQ statements, means: from every object xxx in the sequence of objects, call F(x).

In case of a Where, the object will remain in the resulting sequence if and only if F(x) returns a true value.

So if you wanted all TableRows that have a Title starting with an "A", and an InitialValue smaller than 1.0, your query would be:

```
var result = myTableRows
    .Where(tableRow => tableRow.Title.StartsWith("A") && tableRow.InitialValue < 1.0);
```

[This article really helped me to understand LINQ](https://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you created a repository to access your data. Otherwise, you can just take a look at this documentation page [Asp.net boilerplate repositories](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories)

After that, you can inject your repository using dependency injection [Dependency Injection](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dependency-Injection)

With all this done you can just query from your repository:

```
var myItems = _yourRepository.GetAll().Where(x => x.KeyTaskCheck == true).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you accessing your table from c#? via repository or DBContext or via some other way?

If its via repository then Iwb answer is good.
If its via DBContext then it would be something like below:

```
  yourDBContext.YourTable.Where(x => x.KeyTaskCheck == true).ToList();
```